# Second Admin account on Windows can't kill first's processes

Tags: windows, process, account

So I have this process called svbc_gm.exe, and I start it as the user I've created when installing Windows Server. It is a staple Administrator account. I wrote a small batch script that must work on two users, but it doesn't work two-way for the second Admin account. What I mean is that when I start svbc_gm.exe as first Admin, second can't kill it, but when I start it as second - first has full access over second's process. Note: both accounts are administrators.

So, my question is. What can I do so that when this executable is started by the first Admin, the system automatically allowed the second Admin to do everything with the new process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give any details as far as platform, but it sounds like the system policy is not granting the secondary administrator user the necessary privileges to terminate other users' processes.

If you go to the Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Local Security Settings, then expand Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment, there should be a policy for "Debug Programs". Add the "Administrators" group to this policy, and you should be able to terminate the process from any administrator account.

Comment: Thanks! I only had the user inside, so I did with the group and it worked!